# Use HTML tags inside rows of a table in a render array

Tags: forms, 8

I'm creating a table within a render array.
I can easily create rows within the table like so

```
$rows = [
    'test 1',
    'test 2',
    'test 3',
];
$header = [
    'header 1',
    'header 2',
    'header 3',
];
$render['table'] = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

However when I attempt to include html tags within the row like so:

```
$rows = [
    '<a href="test1">test 1</a>',
    '<a href="test2">test 2</a>',        
    '<a href="test3">test 3</a>',    
];
```

it spits it out with the tags written out. It shows

```
<a href="test1">test 1</a><a href="test2">test 2</a><a href="test3">test 3</a>
```

instead of showing

[test 1](http://test1) [test 2](http://test2) [test 3](http://test3)

Is there a way to use html tags inside rows of a table element in a render array?

UPDATE: 
I've also tried

```
'#rows'    => [
                        'test 1'  => [
                            '#type'  => 'html_tag',
                            '#tag'   => 'h1',
                            '#value' => 'Test 1',
                        ],
                        'test 2'  => [
                            '#type'  => 'html_tag',
                            '#tag'   => 'h1',
                            '#value' => 'Test 2',
                        ],
                        'test 3'  => [
                            '#type'  => 'html_tag',
                            '#tag'   => 'h1',
                            '#value' => 'Test 3',
                        ],
                    ],
```

But that returns a table with 3 rows and 3 columns that say

'html_tag' 'h1' 'Test 1'

'html_tag' 'h1' 'Test 2'

'html_tag' 'h1' 'Test 3'

Instead of actually producing an html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the links using function Drupal::l,

For example,

```
$url = Url::fromUri('http://example.com/');
$link1 = \Drupal::l(t('Link1'), $url);
$url = Url::fromUri('http://example.com/');
$link2 = \Drupal::l(t('Link2'), $url);
$url = Url::fromUri('http://example.com/');
$link3 = \Drupal::l(t('Link3'), $url);
$rows = [
  array(
    $link1,
    $link2,       
    $link3,  
  ),
];
$header = [
    'header 1',
    'header 2',
    'header 3',
];
$render['table'] = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

To add other html tags to table , you can use Drupal markup element and renderer service,

```
$element['#markup'] = '<span>Example Span Tag</span>';
$span_tag = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($element);
```

Comment: This may work for a hyperlink but I have a variety of html tags I need, such as <audio> or <video> tags.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include other html tags in table.

Comment: It you definitely can't trust the render mechanism to create what you need, you can use `Markup::create()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Markup class:

```
Markup::create('<strong>test 1</strong>')
```

Full example with rendering a table can be found here: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-render-table-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid HTML tags being escaped, `#rows` items should be defined as arrays with `data` property. For example:

```
$rows = [
  ['data' => '<strong>test 1</strong>'],
  ['data' => '<s>test 2</s>'],
  ['data' => '<div>test 3</div>'],
];
$header = [
  'header 1',
  'header 2',
  'header 3',
];
$render['table'] = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

I could not find a reference to this in the documentation. Discovered via trial and error.

Comment: Doesn't work, for two reasons. Your `$rows` variable needs another level of array nesting. And even if you add that extra array wrapper the markup is still escaped.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, but this did:

```
$link = Link::createFromRoute('Test', '<front>');
$row['col1'] = ['data' => [ '#markup' => 'Something (' . $link->toString() . ')']];
```